# How to differentiate between a url and string in javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an object which contains `media_id` with some sort of link which is navigating to my Audio screen page and a second `media_id` contains a string which is going to video screen page. How can I tell between them to navigate send them to their specific pages. My code is below:

API:

```
{
        "id": 602,
        "title": "Reflections on Africa",
     "media_id": "https://cdn.islamicmedia.com.au/site/2020/03/2019-11-18-Reflections-on-Africa-by-
    },
{
    "id": 595,
    "title": "Reflections on Africa ",
   ahmed-bassal/",
    "media_id": "8ZVwBwq2cTs",


},`
```

My code (will provide more code if u want). I know I'm doing something wrong so pls correct me

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      item.media_id === String
        ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Video', {
            id: item.id,
          })
        : this.props.navigation.navigate('Audio', {
            id: item.id,



          });
    }}>
```

Comment: You can check if the `media_id` begin with `https or http`, if yes it is url otherwise it will be `id`.

Comment: yes pls..can u give me a code suggestion how to begin with it I will be very thankful to u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for substring as,

```
media_id.includes("https://")
```

or without SSL

```
media_id.includes("https://" | "http://")
```

Now if it either starts with or has another `url` in it. You can differenciate.

The best way is regex

```
function validURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a quick and simple solution is to check if your string contain "https:"
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Comment: hi, how to check if it contains.pls guide me a bit with some code

Comment: sorry the link didn't past xD, if you didn't understand tell me

Comment: pls can u edit my code? I have tried media_id.startsWith("https://") but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startsWith`, which is a method inside any String prototype's.

Try using this on your check:

```
item["media_id"].startsWith("https://")
```

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: Its working now..I am so thankful to all of you..so thankful..can't upvote because my reputation is low. but thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `media_id` begins with `https` using `startsWith`. If it begin with `https` it is an `url` else `id string`.

```js
const input = [{
    "id": 602,
    "title": "Reflections on Africa by Brother Ahmed Bassal",
    "media_id": "https://cdn.islamicmedia.com.au/site/2020/03/2019-11-18-Reflections-on-Africa-by-"
  },
  {
    "id": 595,
    "title": "Reflections on Africa by Brother Ahmed Bassal",
    "media_id": "8ZVwBwq2cTs",
  }
];

input.forEach(({
  media_id
}) => {
  if (media_id.startsWith('https')) {
    console.log('URL', media_id);
  } else {
    console.log('ID', media_id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Its working now..I am so thankful to all of you..so thankful..can't upvote because my reputation is low. but thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Try with a regex

```
//arr is your API result
{this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
         item.media_id.match("^https")
        ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Video', {
            id: item.id,
          })
        : this.props.navigation.navigate('Audio', {
            id: item.id,
          });
    />
  );
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try parsing it, and if it fails, you know it's not an URL! With the advantage of working for any kind of protocol, not just HTTP.

```
function isUrl(thing) {
    try {
        new URL(thing);
        return true;
    } catch (_) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it simply:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
      isUrl(item.media_id)
        ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Audio', {
            id: item.id,
          })
        : this.props.navigation.navigate('Video', {
            id: item.id,
          });
    }}>
```